# Multi-column combobox column widths keep resetting to 1"

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a split-form in MS Access that has a number of long comboboxes. These are based on a lookup table that has the structure [ID], [Descriptor]. The comboboxes are bound to the ID column and the [Descriptor] field displays on the form.
I designed the form with the comboboxes columnwidths property to `"0in.; 20in."`

Our office uses wide monitors that can expand past the max form size of 22" set by Access.

On open and on resize, if expanding, the form reverts the columnwidths to `"0in.; 1in.;"`. This cuts off the text in dropdown list at 1" and the rest of the column is white space.
If the form shrinks, the columns revert to the correct size.

I tried a number of options to fix the issue.
Here's the closest I've gotten, I have it on resize and on open.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim iTwip As Long
    
    iTwip = 1440

    Set frm = Me.Form
    For Each ctl In frm
        If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
            If ctl.Width > (20 * iTwip) Then
                ctl.ColumnWidths = "0in.; 20in."
            Else
                ctl.ColumnWidths = "0in.; " & Format(ctl.Width / iTwip, "##") & "in."
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
    Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Every combination of columnwidths, column(i).width, my_cbobox.width reverts once the form is expanded.

Comment: Are you using anchored comboboxes with the "stretch across top" option selected so the comboboxes automatically resize with the form?  Your code seems to be designed for changes in combobox size but it's not clear where (or if) you are actually resizing the comboboxes themselves.

Comment: Yes the comboboxes are anchored to stretch across the top. That may be the problem, but it's strange that it would affect the dropdown column widths in that way. I've never had that problem before. I'll try un-anchoring them and see if that helps.

Comment: I just created a form and added a combobox of width 1" with 2 columns and a value list rowsource.  I set the anchor option to stretch across top and the columnwidths to 0";1" in design view.  Without any code at all the combo box resizes when the form is maximized and the width of the visible column matches the width of the combo box.  Perhaps you don't require code to do what you need?

Comment: Normally I would just set the anchor and call it a day. I only added the code because of the problem. I was hoping to just be able to brute force it but I think you are correct about the anchoring + stretching the column width past the max 22" parameter that resets the columnwidth to 1". Taking the anchors off seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I am curious, if you don't use the anchor+stretch option, how are you resizing the combobox at runtime?

Comment: On the resize event, get inside form width and calculate corresponding width and placement values for the controls

Answer (score 0):

Based on my tests you can't do things like set controls widths and colors in the resize event.  The code will seem to work but the control settings will not change.  I did manage to set a combobox's background color one time when the form opened but I think that was just a bug.

You can do simple side effects in the resize event.  for instance, I was able to print to debug the size of a combobox whose anchor was set to stretch across bottom.

By the way, you can still adjust control widths and such in singular events that run once like form load and form open so, you can make sure everything starts correctly.

these days how a control on a form behaves when the form is resized is declared at design time with a layout.  you can edit a controls layout under the arrange tab on the ribbon after you have selected the control.
Unless selected, layouts are invisible and can effect many controls so I would save before editing one.
for the final answer, you can have as many layouts as you want so for instance put every combobox that you want to stretch on resize in its own layout with anchoring set to stretch across top,

Comment: You can absolutely set control widths in the form resize event.  It may be the case that using anchors with a 'stretch' option selected overrides this but there is no reason to assume that everyone uses anchored controls this way.

Comment: There are no layouts on the form. I can never get along with them, and I think the benefits of easily creating clean-looking forms is outweighed by the drawback of how rigid the layout structure is.

Comment: all I have to respond with is layouts get auto inserted in a lot of ways and are hard to detect.  My favorite way to detect them is to select the form in design mode.  Then I scroll through the combobox at the top of the properties (sidebar?) looking for names that correspond to invisible controls

Comment: @mazoula There's no layouts on the form. I run a pretty tight ship when it comes to designing forms. Everything is properly labeled and accounted for.